# Error building a console .netcoreapp3.1 app with VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I am building a console HelloWorld .netcoreapp3.1 with VS2019 16.7.5
After the wizard, when building I get the error

```
>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\ConsoleApp2\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

I tried:

```
PM> dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : 'Python 3.6.5' is not a valid version string. (Parameter 'value') [D:\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2.sln]
```

Same results with `nuget restore`.
Yes, I have Python 3.6.5, but even removing from the environment variables, I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever issue you're having is certainly machine specific, and therefore I cannot possibly give you an answer with any certainty, or reproduce it on my machine. I know you said that you removed environment variables, but this is my best guess, as MSBuild automatically imports all environment variables as MSBuild properties.

What you can do is run `dotnet restore -bl`, which will create a `msbuild.binlog` file. Open it with https://www.msbuildlog.com/, and type "python" in the search box. You'll discover where the string is coming from, and how it flows to NuGet's restore. If it's listed as a property at the very beginning of the project evaluation, unless you passed in that string on the command line, it's almost certainly coming from an environment variable.

If you swear it's not an environment variable, in the binlog viewer, you can right click the csproj and choose "preprocess", or run `dotnet msbuild -pp:pp.txt` and open pp.txt in your favorite xml/text viewer. This is the csproj with all MSBuild imports copy/pasted into a single file. If python didn't come in via an environment variable, then it must have come from an import, which will be visible in the preprocessed file.